# Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path ... No such file or directory: Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I just clone the code from my old mac to my New Mac. Code complies successfully but while installing into the simulator/real device and Xcode start giving me this message.

[image]

> Please try again later. Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path
> /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework;
> Extra info about
> "/Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist":
> Couldn't stat
> /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist:
> No such file or directory

So I tried:

1. clean build folder
2. clean Drived Data
3. restart Xcode
4. restart my device

Xcode show me the option to send this issue to apple and I have shared it with apple.

Here is the complete log of the error.

```
    App installation failed: Unable to Install “Cold Water Therapy”
    Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
    Code: 1
    Failure Reason: Please try again later.
    Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework; Extra info about "/Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
    User Info: {
        DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-03-21 19:24:29 +0000";
        IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
        SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
    }
    --
    App installation failed: Unable to Install “Cold Water Therapy”
    Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
    Code: 1
    Failure Reason: Please try again later.
    Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework; Extra info about "/Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
    User Info: {
        IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
        SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
    }
    --
    Unable to Install “Cold Water Therapy”
    Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
    Code: 1
    Failure Reason: Please try again later.
    Recovery Suggestion: Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework; Extra info about "/Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
    --
    Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework; Extra info about "/Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist": Couldn't stat /Users/qaziammar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/84C3DC5A-333E-43B8-B0ED-706B21618311/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.xPJiHO/extracted/ColdWaterTherapy.app/Frameworks/UserMessagingPlatform.framework/Info.plist: No such file or directory
    Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
    Code: 35
    User Info: {
        FunctionName = "-[MIBundle _validateWithError:]";
        LegacyErrorString = PackageInspectionFailed;
        SourceFileLine = 64;
    }
    --
    
    Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
        "device_model" = "iPhone16,2";
        "device_osBuild" = "17.4 (21E213)";
        "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
        "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.24";
        "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.100.58";
        "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
        "launchSession_state" = 1;
        "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
        "operation_duration_ms" = 4071;
        "operation_errorCode" = 1;
        "operation_errorDomain" = IXUserPresentableErrorDomain;
        "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
        "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
        "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
        "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
        "param_debugger_type" = 3;
        "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
        "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
        "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
        "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
        "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
        "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
        "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
        "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
        "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
        "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
        "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
        "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
        "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
        "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
        "param_install_style" = 0;
        "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
        "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
        "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
        "param_launcher_style" = 0;
        "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
        "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
        "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
        "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
        "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
        "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
        "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
        "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.4";
        "sdk_osVersion" = "17.4";
        "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
    }
    --
    
    
    System Information
    
    macOS Version 14.2.1 (Build 23C71)
    Xcode 15.3 (22618) (Build 15E204a)

Timestamp: 2024-03-22T00:24:29+05:00
```

Comment: Goto `Build Settings` and search `INFOPLIST_FILE` property in search bar, Check whether this property correctly set info.plist path or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling all your packages by removing them in the Project Package Dependencies section of your project, and then installing them again.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfuf1.png)